# wifi-led problem with different kernel

Tags: 16.04, wireless, kernel

My Asus A456UR runs Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit, wifi-led is work well when i use kernel 4.8.0-53-generic but always off with another kernel (4.8.0-(except 53), 4.4, 4.9 - 4.11)

is there any way that can be done to change my current kernel (4.10.0-42-generic) configuration in this wifi-led issue accordingly kernel 4.8.0-53-generic?, i can't downgrade my kernel because it's related to nvidia 384 driver

My device is :

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

:~$ modinfo ath9k | grep parm

```
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           led_active_high:Invert LED polarity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `modinfo ath9k | grep parm`

Comment: @chili555 edited sir, so whats wrong with the output?

Comment: Nothing is wrong; it just tells me what parameters that we may try to manipulate!

Answer (score 0):

Please try a driver parameter. From the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k blink=1
```

Does that correct the LED behavior? If so, I will edit this answer to make it permanent. If not, we'll try something else.

Comment: sorry sir it doesn't work, now  i have strange-blinking pop up every time i turn on my wifi with fn+f2

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: i tried but still the same as before

Comment: I'm sorry that I have no other suggestions.